# Immediately Invoked Function Expression For Page Defaults

Tags: javascript, css, dom, iife

I've tried to setup a very "vanilla" approach to this but cannot get the result.

I'm trying to reach into the DOM and the associated div styles using JS and effectively change the "display" property of the CSS.

The JS is error free but the CSS doesn't change.

```js
(function() {
 var singleCard = document.getElementById('card-container');
 var manyCard = document.getElementById('card-container-many');
 var allCard = document.getElementById('card-container') && document.getElementById('card-container-many');

 var singleCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container');
 var manyCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container-many');
 var allCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container') && document.querySelector('#card-container-many');

    if (singleCardCss.display && manyCardCss.display === 'none') {
        allCardCss.display = 'block';
    } else {
        allCardCss.display = 'none';
    }
}());
```

```css
#card-container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 280px;
  height: 310px;
  background-size: 640px 360px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#card-container-many {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 280px;
  height: 310px;
  background-size: 640px 360px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
 <div id="card-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
 <div id="card-container-many"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your placing the IIFE before your CSS, then your IIFE will have nothing to deal with. The CSS applies to the DOM which probably isn't available at the time so there's no `#card-container` yet to target.

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for the comment. I have my local stylesheet linked last in the head of the document. The JS file is the very last item in the body; wrapped in a script tag. This means the CSS should be loading first and the JS file after all page content is loaded right?

Comment: You are 100% correct, sir. Now that that possibility is eliminated, I think I know why your'e not accessing the CSS. See my answer.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the IIFEs, are you saying that it works without them? Do you also have a working non-vanilla solution?

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById` and then `document.querySelector` to get the same elements twice? Judging from your variable names and usage, you meant to do `var singleCardCss = singleCard.style;`

Comment: @Bergi, Why are you here?

Comment: @TheTrain To help you writing better code? Not sure I understood your question.

Comment: @Bergi, can you? You don't seem to know what an IIFE is.

Comment: @TheTrain I do, and that's why I'm questioning your statement "*I'm hoping to use the IIFE to ensure the Div cards are not showing upon page load.*". Whether you wrap your code in an IIFE or not does not affect its functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.style` property is missing. For example:

```
 allCardCss.style.display = 'block';
```

Also, the use of the AND operator is wrong I believe. It should be used in the `if` condition like so:

```
if (singleCardCss.style.display === "none" && manyCardCss.style.display === 'none') {...
```

Each side of the operand must be complete in a conditional even when it's a comparison between 2 objects (`singleCardCSS` and `manyCardCSS`) vs. the same condition (`"none"`).

I took a third look and saw that `allCardCSS` is wrong as well, it should be:

```
var allCardCSS = document.querySelectorAll('div > div');
```

The result will be a NodeList of all divs that are a child of another div (`singleCardCSS` and `manyCardCSS`). This NodeList is an *array-like* object which you can do simple iterations upon in order to access the objects within. Notice how the `for` loop goes through the NodeList `allCardCss`.

Finally on the last statement has been eliminated because the else isn't needed since they are already `.style.display="none"`. The first statements have been eliminated as well because `.getElementById('ID')` is identical to `querySelector('#ID');`

One last thing, I almost forgot about the parenthesis business:

> Either of the following two patterns can be used to immediately invoke
>   a function expression, utilizing the function's execution context to
>   create "privacy."

```
(function(){ /* code */ }()); // Crockford recommends this one

(function(){ /* code */ })(); // But this one works just as well
```

-[Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

So you are ok. The point is that if you have a set of extra parenthesis at the end then that'll be interpreted by the browser as an **E**xpression **F**unction which causes an **I**mmediate **I**nvocation*. The mention of *privacy* is referring to the IIFE with a closure which doesn't apply in your circumstance unless you make the latter part of the code into a function in which case you have a closure. In your case it's not needed since you aren't passing any variables from the outside of your function.

**To those more knowledgeable. If there's anything I've said that to the contrary or omitted, please leave a comment with your downvote.**

*it's IIFE a little mixed up in order in sentence but you get the picture

### Demo

```js
(function() {
  var singleCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container');
  var manyCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container-many');
  var allCardCss = document.querySelectorAll('div > div');


  if (singleCardCss.style.display === "none" && manyCardCss.style.display === 'none') {
  
    for (let i = 0; i < allCardCSS.length; i++) {
      allCardCss[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}());
```

```css
#card-container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 280px;
  height: 310px;
  background-size: 640px 360px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#card-container-many {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 280px;
  height: 310px;
  background-size: 640px 360px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div id="card-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div id="card-container-many"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is very common. You have to remove the last `)` after your function. You close your IIFE after calling it. You can try but your function will be never call! You also can try to delete your variable allCardCss and allCard. I do not understand why do you initialize them with &&.

Replace:

```
(function() {
    var singleCard = document.getElementById('card-container');
    var manyCard = document.getElementById('card-container-many');
    var allCard = document.getElementById('card-container') && document.getElementById('card-container-many');

    var singleCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container');
    var manyCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container-many');
    var allCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container') && document.querySelector('#card-container-many');

    if (singleCardCss.display && manyCardCss.display === 'none') {
        singleCardCss.display = 'block';

    } else {
        allCardCss.display = 'none';
    }
}());
```

By:

```
(function() {
    var singleCard = document.getElementById('card-container');
    var manyCard = document.getElementById('card-container-many');


    var singleCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container');
    var manyCardCss = document.querySelector('#card-container-many');


    if (singleCardCss.display && manyCardCss.display === 'none') {
        singleCardCss.display = 'block';
        manyCardCss.display = 'block';
    } else {
        singleCardCss.display = 'none';
        manyCardCss.display = 'none';
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this didn't work. I've adjusted the closing parens to your suggestion and while I don't get an error either way, the CSS properties are not being changed.